# how can i control overflow of navigation bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

i am trying to make a this navigation bar in single line.but it goes to next line.

**how to control this overflow in single line.**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="col-md-5">
 <div class="nav-tabs-custom">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="text-center tag"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-left next_icon"></span></a></li>
              <li class="active text-center spacer" style="color:black;"><a href="#glyphicon" data-toggle="tab">Today<br> <span><b>21</b></span></a></li>
              <li class="text-center spacer"><a href="#glyphicons" data-toggle="tab">Mon<br> <span><b>22</b></span></a></li>
       <li class="text-center spacer"><a href="#glyphicons" data-toggle="tab">Tues<br> <span><b>23</b></span></a></li>
      <li class="text-center spacer"><a href="#glyphicons" data-toggle="tab">Wed<br> <span><b>24</b></span></a></li>
        <li class="text-center spacer"><a href="#glyphicons" data-toggle="tab">Thur<br> <span><b>25</b></span></a></li>
       <li class="text-center spacer"><a href="#glyphicons" data-toggle="tab">Fri<br> <span><b>26</b></span></a></li>
         <li class="text-center spacer"><a href="#glyphicons" data-toggle="tab">Sat<br> <span><b>27</b></span></a></li>
      <li class="text-center spacer"><a href="#glyphicons" data-toggle="tab">Tues<br> <span><b>23</b></span></a></li>
      <li class="text-center spacer"><a href="#glyphicons" data-toggle="tab">Wed<br> <span><b>24</b></span></a></li>
        <li class="text-center spacer"><a href="#glyphicons" data-toggle="tab">Thur<br> <span><b>25</b></span></a></li>
       <li class="text-center spacer"><a href="#glyphicons" data-toggle="tab">Fri<br> <span><b>26</b></span></a></li>
         <li class="text-center spacer"><a href="#glyphicons" data-toggle="tab">Sat<br> <span><b>27</b></span></a></li>
             
          <li class="text-center tag pull-right"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right next_icon"></span></a></li>
          
   </ul>
 
   </div>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

please help me to solve this.

Comment: It's in single line. What's your screen width?

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you need? As I understand, you need carousel.  
So you should try to find Bootstrap carousel.  
For example:  
https://codepen.io/mephysto/pen/ZYVKRY

Answer (score 1):

Adding this for the smaller contents might work, but the caveat is that you need to control how people might be able to see the rest:

```css
.nav.nav-tabs {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.nav.nav-tabs li {
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav-tabs-custom">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="text-center tag pull-right"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right next_icon"></span></a></li>
    <li class="text-center tag"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-left next_icon"></span></a></li>
    <li class="active text-center spacer" style="color:black;"><a href="#glyphicon" data-toggle="tab">Today<br> <span><b>21</b></span></a></li>
    <li class="text-center spacer"><a href="#glyphicons" data-toggle="tab">Mon<br> <span><b>22</b></span></a></li>
    <li class="text-center spacer"><a href="#glyphicons" data-toggle="tab">Tues<br> <span><b>23</b></span></a></li>
    <li class="text-center spacer"><a href="#glyphicons" data-toggle="tab">Wed<br> <span><b>24</b></span></a></li>
    <li class="text-center spacer"><a href="#glyphicons" data-toggle="tab">Thur<br> <span><b>25</b></span></a></li>
    <li class="text-center spacer"><a href="#glyphicons" data-toggle="tab">Fri<br> <span><b>26</b></span></a></li>
    <li class="text-center spacer"><a href="#glyphicons" data-toggle="tab">Sat<br> <span><b>27</b></span></a></li>
    <li class="text-center spacer"><a href="#glyphicons" data-toggle="tab">Tues<br> <span><b>23</b></span></a></li>
    <li class="text-center spacer"><a href="#glyphicons" data-toggle="tab">Wed<br> <span><b>24</b></span></a></li>
    <li class="text-center spacer"><a href="#glyphicons" data-toggle="tab">Thur<br> <span><b>25</b></span></a></li>
    <li class="text-center spacer"><a href="#glyphicons" data-toggle="tab">Fri<br> <span><b>26</b></span></a></li>
    <li class="text-center spacer"><a href="#glyphicons" data-toggle="tab">Sat<br> <span><b>27</b></span></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: sir i am using width as "col-md-5"

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow : auto` if you want a scrollable navigation bar.

And if you want the navigation bar to be in the same row irrespective of the screen width, use Bootstrap Grids to divide the screen in different parts for different screens.

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp